# On click slidetoggle div but hide others first - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that when a user clicks a title, the following div toggles display.

I want to somehow say if any other divs are display:block then set them to display none first.

I have the following...

```
$('.office-title').click(function(){
     $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
     return false;
});
```

and my html markup is as such...

```
<div class="office-row">
    <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
    <div class="office">sadasd</div>
</div>
<div class="office-row">
    <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
    <div class="office">sadasd</div>
</div>
<div class="office-row">
    <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
    <div class="office">sadasd</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Simply hide all `div`s first, then display this one.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`</office>` is not a valid closing. The closing should be `</div>`

```
<div class="office-row">
        <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
        <div class="office">sadasd</div>
      </div>
    <div class="office-row">
        <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
        <div class="office">sadasd</div>
    </div>
    <div class="office-row">
        <h3 class="office-title">Title</h3>
        <div class="office">sadasd</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.office
{
    display: none;
}
```

and jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.office-title').click(function () {
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle();

        $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
        return false;
    });
});
```

[**HERE YOU CAN CHECK**](http://jsfiddle.net/jubair/nR29B/5/)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it: http://jsfiddle.net/gKgJ7/

```
$('.office-title').click(function(){
   $('.office').slideUp();
   $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
   return false;
});
```

### note:

This is not a valid closing:

```
<div class="office">sadasd</office>
   //---------------------^^^^^^^^----should be </div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to animate the hide @Jai?

Comment: This is the most easy solution

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.office-title').click(function(){
     $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
     $(this).parent(".office-row").siblings().hide(); // this should help
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below... it will work...

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/83/

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.office-title').next('div').slideToggle();
        $('.office-title').click(function(){   
        $('.office-title').next('div').slideUp();
        $(this).next('div').slideToggle(); 
        return false;
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will close all the open div with animation and opens the required div

```
$('.office-title').click(function(){
     var that = $(this);
     if('.office').each(function() {
       if($(this) == $(that).next('div')) {
          $(this).slideToggle();
       }
       else {
          if($(this).css('display')!=='none') {
             $(this).slideToggle();
          }
       }
     });
     return false;
});
```