# How to toggle dynamically created div 's on the basis of class and name attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I am creating **Table of Content** dynamically.

**Hierarchy levels:**

- Parent Div
- Children Div

  - Grand Children Div

For this I am creating div 's dynamically.

Then I am assigning margin to those divs.

**Parent Div :-** No margin

**Children Div :-** `margin-left :15px;`

**Grand Children Div :-** `margin-left :35px;`

So I am able to create table of content dynamically.

**Problem :**

I created more than one parent divs and there sub divs as per hierarchy.
But If I am applying click event on first parent div then that event also getting apply on other parent div why because I am adding click event on class.

In this click I am facing problem in `slideToggle().`
As I am using class so because of this it is getting applied on other also.

Example:

```
$('main_div').haml(['%div.g', {id:'g_' + i', name: i}, Parent Div]);//class = 'g'

$('main_div').haml(['%div.g1', {id:'g_' + i, name: i, style:'**margin-left: 15px**;'}, Children Div]);//class = 'g1'

$('main_div').haml(['%div.g2', {id:'g_' + i, name: i, style:'**margin-left: 35px**;'}, Grand Children Div]);//class = 'g2'
```

In this div **'i'** value is coming from database on with the help of AJAX GET.

So what changes should I do for `slideToggle()` : In this I just want to toggle only clicked parent div's childrens only?

Any hints / suggestions please?

Reference code:

```
$('#main_div').on('click','.g', function(){
  $('#main_div').find('.g1,.g2').slideToggle();

});
```

Comment: Show us the code where you apply slideToggle()

Comment: Do we have any other method other than this if I dont have any child divs but I want to arrange them in parent and child and grand child format?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, slideToggle() is click event for all parents div? Than in function you can use 'this' variable.

```
$(this).find(...some selector for child divs...').slide..
```

Show, please, code for click event?

Comment: Thank you for your acknowledgement. I am able to toggle but at one time i want to toggle one parent's children only not other parents children.

Comment: Yes, only one, use 'find' to find that children in parent $(this).find('.g1').slide(); //this find only childs in current parent

Comment: Tried this but not toggling.

Comment: I got it. Above is working fine now. class g was not parent for class g1 and class g2, that is why it was not working. Thanks

Comment: Do we have any other method other than this if I dont have any child divs but I want to arrange them in parent and child and grand child format?

Comment: Thanks it is working now. I have done changes in DOM. div.g is parent div and other div.gN are children of div.g.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#main_div').on('click','.g', function(){
   $(this).find('.g1,.g2').slideToggle();
});
```

When jQuery calls your click handler it sets `this` to the clicked item, i.e., to the `.g` element, so only apply `.find()` to that item's descendants by using `$(this).find(...`

Comment: Tried this but not toggling.

Comment: I got it. Above is working fine now. class g was not parent for class g1 and class g2, that is why it was not working. Thanks

Comment: Do we have any other method other than this if I dont have any child divs but I want to arrange them in parent and child and grand child format?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Suppose I am having 3 divs (all are main divs) and with the help of margin CSS I will be adding them in hierarchy format(like table of content). If I will click on 1st div then slideToggle of 2nd and 3rd div is possible?

Comment: $('#main_div').on('click','.g', function(){
   $(this).find('.g1,.g2').slideToggle();
});   With example I am able to toggle .g1 and .g2 on clicking .g . But when I click on .g1 then it is getting hide

Comment: Thanks it is working now. I have done changes in DOM. div.g is parent div and other div.gN are children of div.g.

Answer (score 0):

Following Reference Link solved my problem.

[On click slidetoggle div but hide others first - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838074/on-click-slidetoggle-div-but-hide-others-first-jquery)

Thanks to other people also.