# Toggleslide Close when other is click opened

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hope you are all doing well.

I'm trying to figure out a code function, on how to auto close the opened Toggleslide when you open a new or other Toggleslide?

Please see code below:

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pxAg.png)

Can be found at:
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip").click(function() {
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#flip2").click(function() {
    $("#panel2").slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
#panel,
#flip,
#panel2,
#flip2 {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#panel,
#panel2 {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel">Hello world!</div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div id="flip2">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div id="panel2">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [On click slidetoggle div but hide others first - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14838074/on-click-slidetoggle-div-but-hide-others-first-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The most extensible way to achieve this is to use common classes on the elements. Then you can re-use the same JS logic for every instance of the `.flip` and `.panel` elements. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".flip").click(function() {
    let $next = $(this).next(".panel").slideToggle("slow");
    $('.panel').not($next).slideUp('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
.panel,
.flip {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e5eecc;
  border: solid 1px #c3c3c3;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.panel {
  padding: 50px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
<div class="panel">Hello world!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this.

```
$('.title').click(function() {
  $(this).next('div').show();

  $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().hide();
  return false;
});
```

[example here](http://jsfiddle.net/2e64gy1t/)

if you using bootstrap you can use bootstrap accordion.